# How does the cnos-telegraf input plug-in solve the url with parameters？

Tags: telegraf, cnosdb, telegraf-inputs-plugin

I have a problem when I use cnos-telegraf for data writing. Usually, the URL parameter value of the input-http plugin is constant, but my URL has a start time parameter, how to solve it?
I think this kind of URL with time parameters is a common thing for time series databases, so I guess my problem is not very special.
what I found:

```
[[inputs.http]]
  urls = [
    "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk"
  ]
```

What I need:

```
[[inputs.http]]
      urls = [
        "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather/:start_tiem/:end_time?q=London,uk"
      ]
```